# ICal Format - One time import or RSS like functionality?

Tags: icalendar

I'd like to publish a list of events in the iCal format.  If I have a public ICS file that I add/update events on, will clients like Google Reader and Outlook receive those updates automatically?  I.e., does it behave like an RSS feed that gets periodically pinged for changes or is it a one time import?

Answer (score 1):

One time import.  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar), it basically represents a mechanism for sending one or more appointments.

If the iCal is published and updated, and your client can be set to periodically refresh, you may get the effect of a subscription to an RSS, but really it is a series of imports.

Comment: What is the correct way then to publish a changing list of events?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the client is configured.  For instance, in Korganizer I often do one-time imports (e.g. departure times when I book a flight).  But I have other ICS files (e.g. organizational calendars) where I set it do pinging.